# Old Rails 3.2 app with Devise 2.1.2 upgrading to Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm starting a fresh Rails 5 app. `Rails new`

I'd like to keep all my users login information and will be throwing away the rest of the database.

Is this possible? Not sure if I can get out the Devise info?

Comment: It is possible and a variety of other options too.. But I'll suggest keeping necessary backup of login info and recreating full DB again with latest devise update

Comment: Yes. I will keep a backup. In fact I will just keep the old application running until the new Rails 5 version is humming along nice. How do I transfer all the User info and passwords? passwords are encryped...

Comment: I guess you can't, unless you use the same security tokens and keys.. which is not suggested.. .